# App crashes when putSerializable() in onSaveInstanceState is used in fragment code

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im using this library https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper
for accomodating multiple fragments in a single activity. In one of the fragments, I was trying to save the item objects in the fragments recyclerview in `onSaveInstanceState()` method,it works quite alright but when the app loses focus(such as pressing home button),the app crashes(it works well when i exit the app by pressing the back button).
Here is the fragment

```
 public class StylesFragment extends Fragment implements Step {
        private static final String STATE_ITEMS = "items";
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private TAASService mService;
        public ArrayList<CustomStyles> styles;
        public StylesFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            final View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_styles, container, false);
            recyclerView=(RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
            //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mService = ApiUtils.getTAASService();
            if (savedInstanceState==null) {
                loadCustomStyles();
            }else{
                    styles = (ArrayList<CustomStyles>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(STATE_ITEMS);
                    StylesListAdapter adapter = new StylesListAdapter(styles);
                    //do more things

            }
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putSerializable(STATE_ITEMS,styles);
        }


        public void loadCustomStyles() {

          //load from network
        }
```

So I noticed on removing `outState.putSerializable();` .It does not crash the app when the app loses focus,anyone know what is happening here and how i can correct it?Thank you

PS:The laptop I use for coding android is of low quality,so I cant make use of the logcat.Have to assemble,install on my phone,to see how it works.

**UPDATE**

```
public class CustomStyles implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("pk")
    @Expose
    private Integer pk;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private String gender;
    @SerializedName("photo1")
    @Expose
    private String photo1;
    @SerializedName("custom_price")
    @Expose
    private Integer customPrice;
    @SerializedName("designer")
    @Expose
    private Designer designer;

    public Integer getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(Integer pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPhoto1() {
        return photo1;
    }

    public void setPhoto1(String photo1) {
        this.photo1 = photo1;
    }

    public Integer getCustomPrice() {
        return customPrice;
    }

    public void setCustomPrice(Integer customPrice) {
        this.customPrice = customPrice;
    }

    public Designer getDesigner()  {
        return designer;
    }

    public void setDesigner(Designer designer) {
        this.designer = designer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider using emulators (or however else you've been compiling your app) then to see logcat errors.

Comment: Have tried using the Android Studio emulators,says my laptop spec too low ...Tried bluestack too,no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **CustomStyles** class is not serializable

Implement serializable in you class CustomStyles (and also in all custom classes you are using inside CustomStyles class)

```
public class CustomStyles implements Serializable {

    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Are you using any other custom classes inside **CustomStyles**? If yes are they implementing Serializable?

Comment: i have updated my question to include the CustomStyles class...Do I have to implement serializer for the gets and the sets classes?

Comment: Yea you need to implement Serializable in **Designer** class too

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then instead of serializable make you classes parcelable and use **outstate.putParcelableArray(styles)**

Comment: I'll get back to you soon,let me try it out...Thanks